# What is the difference between libraries appengine.api.datastore and com.google.cloud.datastore?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I am developing an appengine project and storing my data using Google Datastore. I am using different Datastore libraries as they are the ones used in the examples, but I find it kind of weird that I have to use both:

If I check the docs for querying, in this example they use this library to process queries:

> com.google.appengine.api.datastore

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/retrieving-query-results

> DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
>   PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q); Entity result =
>   pq.asSingleEntity();

However, in this example to store data, they use

> com.google.cloud.datastore

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities

> Entity task = Entity.builder(taskKey)
>       .set("category", "Personal")
>       .set("done", false)
>       .set("priority", 4)
>       .set("description", "Learn Cloud Datastore")
>       .build();

Right now I am able to use both but I am wondering which one is better for which kind of purpose or if they are just the same libraries with different packages. However, I am looking for a way to remove one of them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`com.google.appengine.api.datastore` - is specifically designed to work from Apps deployed on AppEngine. The API does not work if you later decide to deploy your App elsewhere (e.g. Compute Engine).

`com.google.cloud.datastore` - is the new API that allows you to access Datastore from Apps deployed anywhere, not just AppEngine.

`com.google.appengine.api.datastore` - has some additional features that the other one does not have (at least not yet). For example, `OR` condition in your Datastore queries, ability to integrate with other AppEngine Services such as MemCache, FullText Search, etc.

Comment: So maybe it is better to use the new one ? Unless I require any of the methods not yet included

Comment: For my purpose I have found that appengine's datastore is much powerful.